iOS Firestore permission denied even when using Firebase Authentication
I know this question has been asked a lot but a lot of the solutions say to change the Firestore rules and I don't want to do that. I'm wondering why they aren't working as is since I have authentication set up through Firebase.
I have set up Firebase authentication by adding GoogleService-Info.plist to my project and calling `FirebaseApp.configure() on launch. I'm able to login users without issue, but now when I try to read or write to a collection in Firestore I get an "Missing or insufficient permissions" error.
These are my Firestore rules:
service cloud.firestore {  
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}

This is the function I'm running to add to the Firestore:
    func add_data() async {
        Task {
            do {
                if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser {
                    Firestore.firestore().collection("collection/users/test).addDocument(data: ["Title" : "TEST"])
                }
            }
            catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }

    }

Not sure what else I can do to ensure there are sufficient permissions, and I don't want to change the rules to allow anyone to read/write.
Thanks!

why do you have the Task and the do/catch ?

How else should I catch the error?

Don't you need try await on calling addDocument()? Does your code work if the rule is open without auth (just for testing)? With the current rule, read operation also doesn't work?

Figured it out -- I was writing the document path for the match rules incorrectly. Sorry and thanks!
